# same older dll override existing newer version in bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I've build 2 modules for DNN and they work great. Both modules depend on a separate project, that is included by a dll file. Both installations include that dll to the bin folder.

Now if one of the modules gets an update with a newer included dll (assembly and file version is increased for every new version), the older will be overridden by the new dll.

But what if that situation is reversed? I install a version with the older dll file, will the newer be overridden by the older version? I read somewhere that this shouldn't happen, but can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DotNetNuke manages that for you, as long as you include the version number in the Module install manifest (.dnn file), see here for more information: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/AssemblyComponent.aspx

Comment: Thank you, this is probably the solution. I have to give the extra dll a version. Right now it's using the module version, which is not that same for the extra dll. I'll test it later.